# Using a coroutine as decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous

in this scenario:

```
async def foo(f):
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@foo
async def boo(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

is the call to foo as a decorator for boo decorator an async call?

--First Edit:
Also how does one handle calling chain of coroutines as decorators?

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense. After it runs, `boo` is a coroutine object (not a coroutine function). It's not at all useful to have use `async def` for a decorator. For `wrapper` it could make sense (though you'd probably want to `yield from f(...)`), but not for `foo` itself.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Thanks to @blacknght's comment, considering

```
def foo():
    def wrapper(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        async def wrapped(*args):
             # Some fancy foo stuff
            return await func(*args)
        return wrapped
    return wrapper
```

and

```
def boo():
    def wrapper(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        async def wrapped(*args):
            # Some fancy boo stuff
            return await func(*args)
        return wrapped
    return wrapper
```

as two decorators, and

```
@foo()
@boo()
async def work(*args):
    pass
```

As the `foo` is wrapping the `work` coroutine, the key is to `await` the `func(*arg)` in both decorators.

Comment: Nice solution! I found that you don't need the outer `def`. For example, if you removed `def foo()` and `return wrapper` from the first example, then decorating with `@wrapper` (no parens) would have the same effect.

Comment: You also don't need `async` and `await` in `wrapped`, unless you manipulate the return value. Otherwise, you just add an overhead of a task waiting for another task. Not using `async` also gives the advantage of being able to use the same decorator in normal functions as well. The only advantage of having `async` with a single `return await` is to make it clearly documented the function must be awaited, but that doesn't matter in a decorator wrapper.

Comment: @AndréSassi if you return a normal function instead of a coroutine, it might or not have the intended consequences: the code might execute before the awaited function, or in another thread. See this discussion for more details: https://forum.dabeaz.com/t/should-a-decorator-of-an-async-function-also-be-an-async-function/141/10

Comment: Thanks a lot, really helpful, you can add arguments to foo and boo to pass parameters in the decorator.

Comment: @AndréSassi this is exactly what i want  to do. I want to have a single decorator that works for both async as well as normal function. I didn't used async/await for decorator but when i called it for async functions, it throws error, something like `coroutine object is not iterable/callable`. How to write decorators for both async as well as normal/sync functions?

Comment: @y_159 I think you need to have some kind of conditional logic in your code to define the wrapped function as a coroutine if needed.

Comment: @Juggernaut for example? can you give example?

Comment: I've posted an answer for a decorator that can wrap both sync and async functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77604618/78903

Answer (score 45):

```
def foo(f):
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return await f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@foo
async def boo(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Your decorator needs to be a normal function and it will work fine.

When a decorator is evaluated python executes the method with the function as the argument.

```
@foo
async def boo():
    pass
```

Evaluates to:

```
__main__.boo = foo(boo)
```

If foo is an async function type(**main**.boo) will be a coroutine object, not a function object. But if foo is a regular synch function it will evaluate right away and **main**.boo will be the wrapper returned.

Comment: IMHO this solution is way better than accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternate approach using the `decorator` library (i.e. `pip install decorator` first):

```
import asyncio

import decorator


@decorator.decorator
async def decorate_coro(coro, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        res = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        print(res)


@decorate_coro
async def f():
    return 42


@decorate_coro
async def g():
    return 1 / 0


async def main():
    return await asyncio.gather(f(), g())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
42
division by zero
```

Answer (score 0):

A decorator that works for both sync and async functions:

```
from inspect import iscoroutinefunction
from functools import wraps

def my_decorator(decorator_option=None):
    def decorator(f):
        def shared_logic(*args, **kwargs):
            # Do something with decorator_option, if relevant
            pass

        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            shared_logic(*args, **kwargs)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)

        @wraps(f)
        async def async_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            shared_logic(*args, **kwargs)
            return await f(*args, **kwargs)

        return async_wrapper if iscoroutinefunction(f) else wrapper
    return decorator
```

If the decorator doesn't take any args, the outer function can be removed.

Comment: I think you should `await` `shared_logic()` in your async wrapper.

Comment: It'll need to be an `async def async_shared_logic` then, so a dupe definition of the body. Might as well put that code under `async def async_wrapper`, then? The shared function is for avoiding duplication when there's not enough performance benefit to use async (eg, an `if` condition validator). Async functions can call sync functions directly, but sync functions need to start an async loop first, so the shared function cannot be async.

Answer (score -1):

```py
async def foo(f):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    # wrapper pre-function stuff
    result = await f(*args, **kwargs) # key is to await function's result
    # wrapper post-function stuff
    return result 
  wrapper.__name__ = f.__name__ # for some reason, async wrappers don't do this
  # do it to avoid an error if you use the wrapper on multiple functions
  return wrapper
```

The two key changes are to await the function you are wrapping, as it is an async function, and to change the name of the wrapper function so your program isn't trying to name multiple functions the same thing.