# Chain of coroutines as decorator

Tags: python, decorator, coroutine

After trying to answere my own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043226/using-a-coroutine-as-decorator/) (however partially), something else has remained unknown for me. Consider this scenario:

```
import asyncio

async def first(f):
    async def wrapped():
        await asyncio.sleep(0.3)  # Something time-consuming
        print(f)  # <coroutine object second at 0x7fd39f4ff150>
        await f
    await wrapped()


async def second(f):
    async def wrapped():
        await asyncio.sleep(0.3)  # Something time-consuming
        print(f)  # <function main at 0x7fd39fe7d7b8>
        await f()
    await wrapped()


@first
@second
async def main():
    print('done')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main)
```

As you can see from the `print(f)` inside `wrapped()` coroutine in `first(f)` and `second(f)`, the `first()` takes the `second()` as a coroutine object, but the `second()` takes `main()` as a `function()`. Why is it like this? why is not `second()` taking the `main` as a coroutine too?

Comment: Because [`@e @f def g(): ...` is defined to be `def g(): ...; g = e(f(g))`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [kennytm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224671/kennytm)'s comment,

```
@first
@second
def main():
    print('Done')
```

is equivalent to

```
def main():
    pass
main = first(second(main))
```

Actually, `@g @f def foo()` translates to `foo=g(f(foo)`. So the nearest decorator to the function takes the function itself.