# yield from func() in async function python

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have function named `get_session_` which simple yield session and after just close it.

Now i use decorator `logger_decorator` which wrap my `get_session_` function but there is the problem if my `get_session` is async function i receive an `TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable` 
In case of `get_session` is sync function everything works fine. I try to solve it but i'm stuck with this.

Below are my functions:

```
@logger_decorator()
async def get_session_():
    session_ = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield session_
    except Exception as e:
        print('Session rollback because of exception: %s', e)
        session_.rollback()
    finally:
        session_.close()
```

```
def logger_decorator(event_type=None, *args, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(func):
            @functools.wraps(func)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                s_time = time.time()
                ret = yield from func()
                e_time = time.time()
                duration = e_time - s_time
                print('call function %s with duration %f' % (func.__name__, duration))
                return  ret
            return wrapper
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a coroutine as decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043226/using-a-coroutine-as-decorator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved it

```
 async for i in func():
       result = yield i
```