# Getting Error: ValueError: [TypeError("'coroutine' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]

Tags: python-3.x, api, elasticsearch

```
async def answer_question(QUERY, answer):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        response = await session.post('http://127.0.0.1:5009/answer', json={
            "question": QUERY,
            "passage": answer
        })
        return response.text.replace("\"","")
```

Comment: please don't make us guess what you're trying to solve: tell us what you want to achieve, what you tried, what happened

Answer (score 2):

[TypeError("'coroutine' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have **dict** attribute')]  usually happened when the developer made a mistake using async functions.

Solution: Just have a try by adding '**await**'.

- **async** def answer_question(**request.dict()):
  ...

  await answer_question(QUERY, answer)

Should make sure that **async** functions that **only** contains db process, session management, request send, etc, require '**await**' by default.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: detailed explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043226/using-a-coroutine-as-decorator